# JavaScript global variable trouble

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm having trouble with global variables in JavaScript. From every article I've read a variable declared out of a function has a complete scope. But below `alert(leftMargin);` results in 'undefined' when inside a function;

```
var leftMargin = 36;
alert(leftMargin); /* '36' */

function position(direction) {
    alert(leftMargin); /* 'undefined' */
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `position` function? Maybe there's some code in between which modifies the variable.

Comment: That seems odd, but global variables are simply shortcuts to window properties, so `alert(window.leftMargin);` should give you correct results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you positive it's undefined?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var leftMargin = 36;
    alert(leftMargin); /* '36' */
    function position(direction) {
        alert(leftMargin); /* '36' */
    }
    position();
</script>
```

It alerts 36 twice for me, as expected. It might be unset between defining the `leftMargin` variable and actually calling `position()`.

Comment: Ah yes, it was something else within the function which was spoiling it. I should learn to strip the code down and work back up :)

Thanks for your time.